# Correct term to describe an unpublished research paper?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

I'm planning on putting my research paper on my resume, but it is currently unpublished. I've sent it to a publication journal and it's currently under formal review (not accepted yet).

I don't want to misled employers so do I write:

Research Paper A (**pending publication**)

or

Research Paper A (**submitted for publication**)

Do they both convey the same message?

Comment: Not an expert, but i’d read “pending” as approved and just waiting for a slot, while “submitted” could mean it could still rejected.

Comment: You might get more topical answers on [academia.se].

Comment: I'd put "under review" or something that describes accurately the current state of the publication process. Claiming it has been accepted for publication is wrong if it's still awaiting the result of a review, but equally "submitted for publication" suggests it might still be in their inbox, unread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A research paper that has been submitted for publication, but not yet approved by peer review, is called a [**preprint**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprint).  If the article has passed review and been accepted for publication, but not yet actually published, then it's a [**postprint**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprint).  Note that these are terms that would be well-known within academia or research labs, but not necessarily well-known in the commercial world.

In some fields, preprints are widely read and available in collections called "preprint archives."  One of the oldest and most famous ones is called [arXiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv) and was one of the first large sites on the World Wide Web (which it actually predates).